# Capture data from socket using a serverless infra

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, server, serverless, infrastructure

I have many users, each user has a status, when the status is 1 I want to connect to their own socket and store the info on any DB.

The socket is the same url but depending the user_id sent, I get different info.

Many users can have the status 1 at the same time, even thousands of users.

I have created an EC2 with multiple parallel Nodejs Scripts listening all the time and checking every user in DB and when a user is status 1, the script is connected to the socket and start saving all the info on DB.

The problem is:
If I don't have any user with status 0 I am loosing a lot of money because the server is so big, and also when I the number of users is more than expected the EC2 goes down.

Now I am looking for a possible auto managed solution, could be on AWS or could be on any other cloud service, the thing is that I want a service that easily connects to a socket and scale easily.

FYI: The script will be connected to the socket for a couple of hours getting info, that's why I can't user a lambda function to connect to socket and read the events.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pull all computational processes into a lambda, then communicate with it via EventBridge (Bio-directionally). This will assist in queuing / managing / dead-lettering all messages - freeing up your WS for purely data transference tasks.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'AXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'SXXXXXXXXX',
  region: 'eu-west-2',
})

const eventbridge = new AWS.EventBridge()

const params = {}
eventbridge.putEvents(params).promise()
```